# PDO simple select query using Oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I want to try to run simple select query to know if the database connection is working fully.

Here is some PHP code I have tried to execute:

```
$tns = "
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = COD3R-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
       ";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns, '****', '****');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Connected to database';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
/*if($_POST['searchFilter']){
    $searchFilter = $_POST['searchFilter'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ROOM, GUEST_NAME FROM RESERVATION_GENERAL_2 WHERE ROOM LIKE ? OR GUEST_NAME LIKE ?");
    $stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchFilter.'%','%'.$searchFilter.'%' ));
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    if (empty($results)){
      print_r(json_encode(0));
    }
    else{
    print_r(json_encode($results));
    }
}*/
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM RESERVATION_GENERAL_2");
$stmt->execute(array($stmt));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

The only message I got is `Connected to database`. I am not sure if it is really connected to database or not, because I don't know about try and catch. And after that there is a blank page.

See the screenshot for the table name and columns:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you write further code to actually print something on success? Returned rows are a pretty good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$stmt->execute(array($stmt));
```

To:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

You don't have any parameters to execute, in the scenario below it would work:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM RESERVATION_GENERAL_2 WHERE reservation_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($id));
```